# Why I am getting NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/statistics/IOStatisticsSource

Tags: .net, azure, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to get data from Azure Data Lake gen2 (storage account) using .NET spark(3.0.1) and hadoop (3.2.2). I was following [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/spark/how-to-guides/connect-to-azure-storage) and I was getting the following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.SecureAzureBlobFileSystem error. After this I added hadoop-azure-3.3.1 jar and now I am getting NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/statistics/IOStatisticsSource.

Below is the code I am trying:

```
namespace MySparkApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SparkSession spark =
                SparkSession
                    .Builder()
                    .AppName("word_count_sample")
                    .GetOrCreate();
    
            DataFrame df=spark.Read().Json("abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/sample/data/file.json");

            df.Show();

            spark.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing hadoop-* jars of different releases. fix: don't do that

Comment: dont understand the downvote here given it is *exactly* the problem, as in "i have hadoop 3.2.2 and added the hadoop-aws-3.3.1 jar and am now suprised things don't link"